# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm receiving this error "***String was not recognized as a valid DateTime***" with the code below:

```
DateTimeOffSet dt=new DateTimeOffset(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt")));
```

It works in DEV environment but not in Production.

Could anyone please advice what's wrong with the code above?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the culture on the server different than on the workstation?

Comment: Yes, I think. Dev server is hosted locally and prod somewhere in overseas data centre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert.ToDateTime uses current culture information about DateTime format.
Try something like this:

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
string stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. Not sure what "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" does. My requirement is to pass get the NZ Date Time.

Comment: Well, suppose you have format "dd/MMMM/yyyy". Then your date needs to know how to resolve full month name - June, Июнь or Juin for example. Also '/' symbol is not literal - it is date delimiter. For US it is really '/', for Russia it is '.'. All this details are get from IFormatProvider. InvariantCulture ensures that conversion goes both way whenever culture is set on server.

Comment: In other words, format sets general template for conversion. IFormatProvider sets concrete substitution elements for this template.

Comment: what about time, how does it know whether to get US time or NZ time. Thanks.

Comment: If you know for sure that you need NZ culture and hard-coding culture in code is OK for you needs - you can always write
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-NZ");
and then pass culture variable instead of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: Tried this but still showing local time, was expecting to see german time :
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
            string stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, culture);
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, format, culture);
            Console.Write(new DateTimeOffset(dateTime));
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Console.Write() outputs via ToString(). ToString uses current culture :)

Comment: Try Console.Write(stringDate) or at least Console.Write(dateTime.ToString(format, culture))

Comment: still shows current local time :-(
Console.Write(dateTime.ToString(format,culture));

Comment: Do you want to see this time in German timezone? The thing is that your format doesn't have timezone information, so after parsing is has DateTime.Kind=Unspecified. So when you construct DateTimeOffset from it - it falls back to your local timezone.
I'm not sure I understand your goals now...

Comment: When I try it on my box with "de-DE" I get "14.06.2011 04:46 " which is definitely not my local format. Pay attention to '.' as date separator and absence of AM/PM

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting from `DateTime` to `string` and then back to `DateTime`?

I think this should work fine:

```
DateTimeOffset dt = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Um, sorry, but if that code snippet in the question is just to illustrate the problem let me know and I'll revise.

Comment: Thanks @sbarro, I had to convert to ToString to format the date in dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt. This is the requirement I've.

Answer (score 0):

The CultureInfo must be difference on both machine. You may have to pass it in your Convert method as preferred culture e.g. En-US.