# DateTime.Parse throws exception when parsing string

Tags: c#

I have some client code that sends date in the following format `"1/31/2013 11:34:28 AM";`

I am trying to cast it into DateTime object

```
string dateRequest = "1/31/2013 11:34:28 AM";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateRequest);
```

this throws

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

how can i cast it?

Comment: Depends on your [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx), I would guess.

Comment: can you elaborate, how can this be resolved? this code is a part of backend that client from different culture in all parts of the world use

Comment: Personally, I would use one of those [`DateTime.Parse` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c(v=vs.110).aspx) that accept a culture and pass a fixed value. E.g. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @user829174 Where does this string come from?

Comment: This code is coming from Javascript. Can you share code of how to resolve this?

Comment: how on earth this error occurred `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` i tried in vs2010 and no error. `:D` [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6337680/1080742) [2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1825439.aspx/1) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123145/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.ParseExact` with specific format(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the [`DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) overload and specify culture-specific information ( or InvariantCulture).

```
DateTime.Parse("1/31/2013 11:34:28 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also create a specific culture with something like:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

Or use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the format string.

Comment: You need to be a careful to know the format of the input string, it varies between cultures. f.ex. `"1/5/2013 11:34:28 AM"` interpreted using the en-US culture results in `Saturday January 5` whereas using the en-GB cutlure results in `Wednesday May 1`.